# How to hide some text if there is no space in JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, kotlin, jlabel

I have some long text in a JLabel e.g. *"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"*. I want to hide some text if the user resizes the window and there is no much space. I want to get something like this *"Lorem ipsum dolor sit..."*. Is it possible in a JLabel or JTextArea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JLabel` by default will truncate text with an ellipsis (...) if it detects that there is not enough space to display the text. However, if you are using a layout manager in your application then whether or not there is enough space is up to the opinion of the layout manager. For example, `BoxLayout` and the default layout will pay attention to the size of the window and allow the label to truncate:

```
fun labelInBoxLayout() {
  val frame = JFrame()
  frame.size = Dimension(300, 200)
  val panel = JPanel()
  panel.layout = BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)
  val longString = "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWW"
  val label = JLabel(longString)
  panel.add(label)
  frame.add(panel)
  frame.isVisible = true
}
```

whereas `FlowLayout` will insist that the label should continue for the full width of its text regardless of current window width:

```
fun labelInFlowLayout() {
  val frame = JFrame()
  frame.size = Dimension(300, 200)
  frame.layout = FlowLayout()
  val longString = "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWW"
  val label = JLabel(longString)
  frame.add(label)
  frame.isVisible = true
}
```

I found the same to be true for `BorderLayout` and `SpringLayout`, as well as a `BoxLayout` `JPanel` nested inside of a `FlowLayout` `JFrame`. If you have control over which layout you use in your application I recommend experimenting with different ones to find which have the desired effects. Remember that you can add layouts to `JPanel`s, so you can start with a frame-wide layout that allows for truncation and then use other layouts in specific sub-sections of your frame.